# I can't get the text from an Dialog Alert from the Test Class

Tags: java, testing, javafx, junit, hamcrest

Good morning,
i am doing a test class for one javafx class, im trying to control errors right now. When an error ocurred shows me a Dialog Alert with a message who explain the error. I want to compare this message with other in my test class.
Thats last thing that i try.
**LOGIN CLASS**

```
catch (ServerConnectionErrorException ex) {
            LOGGER.warning("LoginWindowController: Server connection error");
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Server Error");
            alert.setContentText("Unable to connect with server");
            Label serverErrorContext = new Label();
            serverErrorContext.setText(alert.getContentText());
            serverErrorContext.setId("serverErrorContext");
            alert.showAndWait();
        }
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
@Test
    public void test4_ConnectionError(){
        clickOn("#txtLogin");
        write("user");
        clickOn("#txtPass");
        write("BBccd1234");
        clickOn("#btLogin");
        FxAssert.verifyThat("#serverErrorContext",LabeledMatchers.hasText("Unable to connect with server"));
        clickOn(".button");

    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Please provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @hotzst verify if the alert that shows got the correct error message, for example if i try to connect to server and can't establish the connection should shows me a Server error just check that its a Server error and not a Username Error for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally instance of check if the contentText was same like the message that should show, i decide to declare one button for every alert and assign it an id. Every id is unique so is impossible that the robot click on other button and if the allert don't shows correctly the test gona be a wrong.
**MAIN CLASS**

```
Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
            alert.setTitle("Server Error");
            alert.setContentText("Unable to connect with server");
            Button errorButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
            errorButton.setId("serverConnectionError");
            alert.showAndWait();
```

**TEST CLASS**

```
clickOn("#txtLogin");
        write("user");
        clickOn("#txtPass");
        write("BBccd1234");
        clickOn("#btLogin");
        FxAssert.verifyThat("#serverConnectionError",isEnabled());
        clickOn("#serverConnectionError");
```